# How can know which external dependencies from a java maven project and do its bazel build/compile

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-2, maven-3, bazel

I'm trying to do with bazel build,  this is java maven project, how can I know which external dependencies and include it in workspace file to a bazel build?

there is a  migration--tooling: https://github.com/bazelbuild/migration-tooling,  what is the maven_project path as following? I tried it as document guidance and can not create generate_workspace.bzl file

```
bazel run //generate_workspace -- --maven_project=/path/to/maven/project
```

this is build output:

```
jias-mbp:migration-tooling me$ bazel run //generate_workspace -- --maven_project=/Users/me/fe/testbazel/guava-master/guava
INFO: Analysed target //generate_workspace:generate_workspace (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //generate_workspace:generate_workspace up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/generate_workspace/generate_workspace.jar
  bazel-bin/generate_workspace/generate_workspace
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.325s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action

INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/generate_workspace/generate_workspace '--maven_project=/Users/me/fe/testbazel/guava-master/guava'
二月 03, 2018 3:02:38 下午 com.google.devtools.build.workspace.maven.DefaultModelResolver getRawModel
警告: Unable to resolve raw Maven model from /Users/me/fe/testbazel/guava-master/guava/pom.xml: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.google.guava:guava:[unknown-version]
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.google.guava:guava-parent:HEAD-jre-SNAPSHOT: Could not find any repositories that knew how to resolve org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:9 (checked ) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ com.google.guava:guava-parent:HEAD-jre-SNAPSHOT, /Users/me/fe/testbazel/guava-master/pom.xml

二月 03, 2018 3:02:38 下午 com.google.devtools.build.workspace.maven.DefaultModelResolver getEffectiveModel
警告: Unable to resolve Maven model from /Users/me/fe/testbazel/guava-master/guava/pom.xml: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.google.guava:guava:[unknown-version]
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.google.guava:guava-parent:HEAD-jre-SNAPSHOT: Could not find any repositories that knew how to resolve org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:9 (checked ) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ com.google.guava:guava-parent:HEAD-jre-SNAPSHOT, /Users/me/fe/testbazel/guava-master/pom.xml

Wrote /private/var/tmp/_bazel_me/e6e7b644943af30a55bb6d7b73aaa3a3/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/generate_workspace/generate_workspace.runfiles/__main__/generate_workspace.bzl
```

Comment: Hi @Oleg,  thanks,  can you pls specify it,  I am reading the doc, 
 https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/generate-workspace.html,  but still not understand how can do it

Comment: What do you mean by "tried it in my local"? `--maven_project` accepts the path to the folder of your Java project that's built with Maven.

Comment: Hi @Jin Thanks for your response, currently I am learning bazel and I will try to build with bazel with a maven project,  I did step as this guide docs.bazel.build/versions/master/generate-workspace.html,  can you help take a look above build output and see what is wrong? thank you

Comment: @Jin . can you advise how to fix bazel build error , thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605528/bazel-build-is-not-working-on-from-maven-project

Answer (score 0):

`migration-tooling` has been deprecated, please instead use [rules_jvm_external](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/) to manage your Maven dependencies.