# Bazel build is not working on from Maven project

Tags: maven, dependencies, bazel, bazel-aspect

I'm new to Bazel and learning its build work, currently I am trying to do with bazel build from a Maven project, please advise me how to make it working, thanks.

Here is the **WORKSPACE** file I am trying to define:

```
maven_jar(
  name = "junit",
  artifact = "junit:junit:3.8.1",
)

maven_jar(
  name = "log4j1",
  artifact = "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.6.2",
)

maven_jar(
  name = "log4j2",
  artifact = "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.6.2",
)
.....
```

Here is the **BUILD** file I am trying to define:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

java_binary(
    name = "everything",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**"]),
     main_class = "src/main/java/com/test/test/test/App",
    deps = [
    "@junit//jar",
    "@log4j1//jar",
    "@log4j2//jar",
    "@jackson//jar",
    "@jsonsimple//jar",
    "@commonsdbutils//jar",
    "@commons//jar",
    "@guava//jar",
    "@poi//jar"],

)
```

Here is I got Bazel build results:

```
mbp:bazel_test me$ bazel build //:everything
INFO: Analysed target //:everything (1 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
    ERROR: /Users/me/git/test/test/BUILD:4:1: Building everything-class.jar (104 source files) failed (Exit 1)
    src/main/java/com/test/test/test/Testapp.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
                                      ^
      symbol:   class Cell
      location: program package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel
      .....
      Target //:everything failed to build
```

Comment: What's the definition for the "poi" `maven_jar` in your `WORKSPACE` file?

Comment: Hi @László,  thanks for update, it is define this in WORKSPAC, I am not sure if this is correct?                                                                                   
    maven_jar(
  name = "poi",
  artifact = "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9",
)

Comment: Thanks! I'll answer in the answer section below.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

- The `main_class` attribute should use dots instead of slashes:

```
 java_binary(
    name = "everything",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    main_class = "src.main.java.com.test.test.test.App",
    ...
```

- There's no `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell` class in the poi jar.

Find the jar's name:

```
$ bazel query --output=build @poi//jar
...
java_import(
  name = "jar",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  jars = ["@poi//jar:poi-ooxml-3.9.jar"],
  srcjar = "@poi//jar:poi-ooxml-3.9-sources.jar",
)
```

The package's location is `$(bazel info output_base)/external/poi`,  and now we know (from the `srcs` attribute in the `bazel query` output above) that the file is called `poi-ooxml-3.9.jar`:

```
$ unzip -l $(bazel info output_base)/external/poi/jar/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar | grep "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel"
        0  2012-11-26 17:14   org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/
     2970  2012-11-26 17:14   org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.class
```

Comment: Thanks for providing some detail.  What is the actual fix?  How to find the bazel target of the correct jar file?